# AngularJS : Fetching Service Data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

**OBJECTIVE**

Have Angular access a Service, retreive information, and display Service Information in two different controllers (later these controllers will manipulate this data, independently).

**LIVE DEMO**
http://plnkr.co/edit/pqnt5IHr3N3oUynfbz37?p=preview

### **index.html**

```
<html ng-app='plunker'>

<head>
  <title>AngularJS - Searching Text</title>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-rc.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Search & Reverse Text</h1>

  <h2>Original Sentence sent to Service</h2>
  <form>
    <input type='text' ng-model='value' placeholder='insert sentence' />
    <button ng-click='setString(value)'>Set</button>
    <pre>Sentence: {{value}} </pre>
  </form>

  <div ng-controller='myController1'>
    <h2>Controller 1 fetching from Service</h2>
    <pre>{{fetch1}}</pre>
  </div>

  <div ng-controller='myController2'>
    <h2>Controller 2 fetching from Service</h2>
    <pre>{{fetch2}}</pre>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

### **app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

/*Service to pass data between controllers */
app.service('passData', function() {
  $scope.stringValue = {};

  $scope.getString = function() {
    return stringValue;
  },

  $scope.setString = function(value) {
    stringValue = value;
  }
});

/* Controller1 catched string from  original sentence */
app.controller('myController1',['passData', function($scope) {
  $scope.fetch1 = passData.getString();
}]);

/*Controller2 catched string from  original sentence */
app.controller('myController2', ['passData', function(scope){
  $scope.fetch2 = passData.getString();
}]);
```

**QUESTIONS**

1. How can I check if the service is catching the original sentence?
2. Why is it that both {{fetch1}} and {{fetch2}} aren't displaying properly?
3. Is this a proper use of services interacting with controllers? Are there better ways?

Comment: start by reading docs for service...a service has no `$scope`.. Also read docs for controller and how to properly inject dependencies. Suggest you closely study some tutorials. A lot of issues in your small little app already...and most importantly learn to use browser console to look for errors

Comment: You're right - stepping a bit outside my comfort zone with Angular and have a rough understanding of all the intricacies - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your html, you are calling setString. If your intent was to call a service method via HTML, it wont work. You need to inject the service to controller, expose its method via controller and then call the exposed method from HTML.

Second you have not injected $scope to the controllers. This is way you get {{fetch}} in view

```
/* Controller1 catched string from  original sentence */
app.controller('myController1',['$scope', 'passData', function($scope, passData) {
  $scope.fetch1 = passData.getString();
}]);

/*Controller2 catched string from  original sentence */
app.controller('myController2', ['$scope','passData', function($scope, passData) {
  $scope.fetch2 = passData.getString();
}]);
```

But the way you have injected the service into the controller is correct

Hope this helps